# /sys/bus/usb/drivers/r8712u/new_id is unchangable

Tags: filesystem

I got my newly purchased wireless stick to work, but I had to change the /sys/bus/usb/drivers/r8712u/new_id file during the process. I somehow managed to add the string "050d 11f1" to it, but it seems that this file is somehow not possible to edit. When I try to edit it **sudo vim new_id** with vim and want to save it (wq!) afterwards, vim exclamates:

```
ew_id [+] Line:1/1[100%]Col:1Buf:#1[48][0x30]                                                                                                                                                                                                 
"new_id"
"new_id" E667: Fsync failed
```

The same with geany/nano/gedit. I simply cannot edit propperly this file, I can just somehow add stuff...

I assume that some privileged process is constantly polling the file and doing I/O operations on it. What's the exact reason and how to successfully edit it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason for your problem, but one solution would be to edit the file using a text editor on a live Ubuntu (or any distro) disc.

Comment: Not possible. /sys exists only in memory, it isn't written to disk.

Answer (score 0):

This file is not mean for editing.

You can try: echo "050d 11f1" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/r8712u/new_id